# Can I use blender to add subtitle to a video?

Tags: blender, subtitle

I want to use Blender to add a subtitle for my video(NOTE:IT IS A .SRT or .ASS FILE but not add a text),but I can not find the button.How to do it?

Comment: You might want to look at ffmpeg, I think it can do this.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It took me a whole night to install Ffmpeg,it looks good.

Comment: 4 downvotes with no explanation of why?

Comment: Typically, Stackoverflow prefers questions more related to computer programming. A better place to ask a question like this might be http://blender.stackexchange.com/ or maybe even http://superuser.com/

Comment: Possibly useful: https://github.com/doakey3/Subsimport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While blender recently got a feature to [export srt files](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/strips/effects/text.html) from text strips added in the VSE, it does not support muxing an srt file into a video. It also does not have a feature to import or display srt text within the VSE.